# azure media service video trim without encoder

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using `azure media service` to store my assets like video. Now i want to `trim` video to first one minute. suppose video is `5 minute` then i want to trim it to `first 1 minute`. I tried with following code

```
{  
  "Version": 1.0, 
  "Sources": [
    {
      "StartTime": "00:00:04",
      "Duration": "00:00:16"
    }
  ],  
  "Codecs": [  
    {  
      "KeyFrameInterval": "00:00:02",  
      "SceneChangeDetection": true,  
      "H264Layers": [  
        {  
          "Profile": "Auto",  
          "Level": "auto",  
          "Bitrate": 4500,  
          "MaxBitrate": 4500,  
          "BufferWindow": "00:00:05",  
          "Width": 1280,  
          "Height": 720,  
          "BFrames": 3,  
          "ReferenceFrames": 3,  
          "AdaptiveBFrame": true,  
          "Type": "H264Layer",  
          "FrameRate": "0/1"  
        }  
      ],  
      "Type": "H264Video"  
    },  
    {  
      "Profile": "AACLC",  
      "Channels": 2,  
      "SamplingRate": 48000,  
      "Bitrate": 128,  
      "Type": "AACAudio"  
    }  
  ],  
  "Outputs": [  
    {  
      "FileName": "{Basename}_{Width}x{Height}_{VideoBitrate}.mp4",  
      "Format": {  
        "Type": "MP4Format"  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

My question is , is there any way to trim video without specifying video `codecs` because i just want to trim video don't want to encode. like using this code

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "Sources": [
    {
      "StartTime": "00:00:00",
      "Duration": "00:01:00"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
      "FileName": "$filename$.mp4",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "MP4Format"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want an output MP4 for downloading/delivering offline.

If the following conditions are satisfied:

1. Source is an MP4 file, or it uses video/audio codecs that are compatible with the MP4 file format (eg. H.264 video, AAC audio), and
2. The source is encoded with closed GOPs

Then, you should be able to use the following preset JSON, that tells the encoder to copy the input video and audio:

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "Sources": [
    {
      "StartTime": "00:00:00",
      "Duration": "00:01:00"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
      "FileName": "$filename$.mp4",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "MP4Format"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Codecs": [
    {
      "Type": "CopyVideo"
    },
    {
      "Type": "CopyAudio"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what if i don't have source in mp4 format like `.mov`. Is there any solution? is there any document regarding this?

Comment: is it possible to generate thumbnil with CopyVideo and Copy audio as codec with thumbnil configuration?